# Using inbuilt Fingerprint Scanner .NET

Tags: .net, serial-port, fingerprint

I am making an application and I wanted to ask if I can interface the inbuilt fingerprint scanner (of a HP laptop) in my .NET application

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason why you couldn't, especially if it's connected as a serial port device (as implied by the tags you used on the question).

However, that's not the end of it. You need to know how to communicate with the device, and you need to know how to make sense of the data it sends you. Now, some devices give you a fully functioning ActiveX component you can just import into your project and it handles everything for you. Otherwise, you're going to want to consult the documentation of the particular device on your computer, and see if it's workable.

There's SDKs that work with .NET (like http://www.griaulebiometrics.com/page/en-us/grfinger_sdk, http://www.digitalpersona.com/Developer-Tools/SDKs/Software-Development-Kits/), and C SDKs are usually quite easy to interface with from .NET as well.

Comment: I wanted to ask if I can use any PINVOKE (or native) libraries. (Those machines also have some interaction layer)

Comment: @CoderGuy Of course, you can use P/Invoke against any C library. So get a lib that can work with your fingerprint scanner, and use it.